# Expression for the gradient of gravity potential in spherical coordinates

Tags: gravity

I am currently using the GGM05C Stokes' coefficients to reconstruct the gradient of gravity potential of Earth.

I have found an expression for said gradient in spherical coordinates in [this technical report by the ICGEM](http://icgem.gfz-potsdam.de/str-0902-revised.pdf). In particular, equation 122 on page 23 shows the partial derivatives of the gravity potential $W$ with respect to the three spherical coordinates parameters $r$ (distance to center), $\lambda$ (longitude) and $\varphi$ (geocentric latitude).

These equations involve the use of associated Legendre functions $P_{lm}$, which are a function of the latitude $\varphi$. I understand then that, when performing the partial derivatives with respect to $r$, $\varphi$ and $\lambda$, the Legendre functions remain unaltered in the derivatives with respect to $r$ and $\lambda$, since the Legendre functions are not a function of either $r$ or $\lambda$. However, since they are a function of the latitude $\varphi$, when we calculate $\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial \varphi}$, we need to derive the associated Legendre functions, obtaining the following expression, as indicated in equation 122 of the linked document:

$$
\dfrac{\partial W}{\partial \varphi} = \frac{GM}{r}\sum_{\mathscr{l}=0}^{\mathscr{l}_{max}}\left(\frac{R}{r}\right)^\mathscr{l}\sum_{m=0}^{\mathscr{l}}\dfrac{\partial P_{\mathscr{l}m}(sin\ \varphi)}{\partial \varphi}\left(C_{\mathscr{l}m}^Wcos(m\lambda)+S_{\mathscr{l}m}^Wsin(m\lambda)\right)
$$

However, following the chain rule, shouldn't this derivative also include a multiplication by $cos\ \varphi$, since that is the derivative of the $sin\ \varphi$ nested within $P_{\mathscr{l}m}(sin\ \varphi)$?

Comment: I don't think so. $\frac{\partial P(\sin(x))}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial P(\sin(x))}{\partial \sin(x)} \frac{\partial \sin(x)}{\partial x}$

Comment: Indeed, I see, I didn't properly read the notation. It is in fact the values of $\dfrac{\partial P(sin(x))}{\partial sin(x)}$ that are known, and since $\dfrac{\partial sin(x)}{\partial x}=cos(x)$, we get the two components required to calculate the derivative. Thanks! Feel free to post it as answer and I will mark it as accepted :)

Comment: I remember that I got really confused with spherical harmonics when I had to deal with them in the context of Rossby waves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chain rule is already included, since the derivative is taken with respect to $\varphi$. Note that
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial P_{\ell m}(\sin(\varphi))}{\partial \varphi} = \frac{\partial P_{\ell m}(\sin(\varphi))}{\partial \sin(\varphi)}  \frac{\partial \sin(\varphi)}{\partial \varphi}.
\end{equation}